# one error message for multiple fields

Tags: jquery, validation

**How can I display one error message after validating multiple fields?**

For example if i have 3 grouped text fields and i would like to show an error message ONLY after validating all three fields.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery validation plugin, especially the parts around groups:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: Thanks but I am not keen on using that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With no code example of the form, I'm not sure what you are validating against or if each field had a unique validation, so I had to guess:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/vVe3r/3/

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" /><br />
<input type="text" /><br />
<input type="text" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

```
$(function() {
    $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var validfields = true;
        $("input").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === "") {
                validfields = false;
            }
            if (!validfields) {
                $("#error").html("<span style='color:red'>Error in form</span>");
            }else{
                $("#error").html(""); //if submit posts back to same page
                $("#myForm").submit();
            }
    });
});
    $("input").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $("#error").html("<span style='color:red'>Error in form</span>");
        }else{
            $("#error").html("");
        }
    }); 


});
```

Comment: Thanks...here's the link to another post...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458047/multiple-field-validations-with-one-error-message

Comment: @jqs You commented in that post that you got the onblur so you should be able to add that to the validation of the submit function.

Comment: I do not want the onSubmit...just the onBlur... please.

Comment: @jqs I added a blur function per your request. It would be helpful in the future if you put all your requirements in your question. From the code example I gave you, you should be able to figure it out now.

Comment: @Jen: You are super quick. Thats exactly what I have done so far...as you can see from your example that the error message disappears when you move from one field to the other.
trying this sequence... Without entering anything in the first field if you move on to the next field---the error message appears which is correct, but now if I enter something in the second field the error message disappears..which doesnt look right. I would like the error message to stay until all the fields entered are correct.
Here's how I would like it to work:::

Comment: If the field is blank OR if the validation is wrong then highlight the field with a red border and show the error message.

If the first field is blank then highlight the field and show the error message...if the second field has passed the validation and is not blank THEN the error message stays coz the first field is not correct but the second field will have its normal styles.

If all the three fields have passed the validation then the error message disappears and the default label text appears.

Comment: @jen: Apologies for not adding the requirements in the question.

Comment: I would like to treat these three fields as a group with a single label and error message....

Comment: @jqs I know exactly how to do it. But I believe only one of us is getting paid to do this work. I pointed you in the right direction, you can finish.

Comment: Well..I was stuck with this problem that y I posted here to see if I cud get any help. Anyways...thnks.